# Proper way to add c++ includes to eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, package, include, eclipse-cdt

I normally use eclipse for java, now I need to do some cpp stuff. I'm using vcpkg for dependency management and cmake to build by binary:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$VCPKG_CMAKE"
```

which is working fine. However, eclipse cannot find these dependencies and what I did was:

- project properties / c/c++ general / paths and symbols / gnu c++

and added

```
$VCPKG_HOME/packages/$SOME_PACKAGE/include
```

which works i guess, but there has to be a better way to do this?

I want to include (make available to eclipse) all that can be found at:

```
$VCPKG_HOME/packages/*/include
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I added cmake4eclipse add built the project with that, under project properties added under:

```
c++ build / cmake4eclipse / symbols(tab)
```

CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$VCPKG_CMAKE

and that sorts that out.

You could probably just add include as described above to the path:

```
$VCPKG_HOME/installed/x64_linux/include
```

or something like that depending on your OS. Haven't tried that dough. For help on cmake4eclipse you should checkout eclipse help / cmake4eclipse

Comment: I just add that the plug-in won't be needed anymore starting from eclipse 2020-09 with CDT 10.0